# Are there downloadable versions of the Canadian VNC and VTA charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, visual-flight-rules, transport-canada

Are there PDF versions of Canadian VNC and VTA charts available for download? I fly in Australia where airservices lists them on their website so I was hoping to find something similar for Canada.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plan to produce electronic versions but they don't seem to be available yet and you can still only order paper ones.  Go here:

http://www.navcanada.ca/EN/products-and-services/pages/aeronautical-information-products-charts.aspx

Comment: Do you have any reference to the planned electronic version introduction of those (official announcement, ...)?

Comment: Well this is disappointing.  My information was quite out of date.  It seems Nav Canada has decided to farm out Canadian charts to Foreflight, which requires you to buy their subscription.  https://www.foreflight.com/support/faqs/canada/

Comment: Also: http://www.navcanada.ca/EN/media/pages/publications-corporate-direct-route-story-2.aspx